# My blower has stopped working with heater or a/c

Tags: chevrolet, hvac, heater-blower, silverado

I have a 2005 Chevy Silverado 1500 HD SL Crewcab. The blower has stopped working with the heater or a/c. I have checked all the fuses I can find in the owners guide and they are good, don't see and problems with wiring or connections,

Comment: Does it have a switch to control the fan or is it an auto temp control unit? (Probably not auto if this is an SL model, but need to check.)

Comment: I have one and the same thing is happening. If I kick/tap the unit on the passenger side floor board it will work but only on the two highest speeds, nothing else...very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Has it stopped working completely, or just on certain speeds? It's possible that the resistor pack ( the thing that controls the speed of the fan ) might have failed...